# well-formed JWT but still getting merchant_error

Tags: android-pay, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to set up In-App Payments for a Chrome Packaged App. When I switch the SellerSecret and SellerIdentifier from the sandbox to my own I get an merchant_error when I call buy().

As far as I can tell, this error seems to indicate that the JWT is not well-formed (but the only difference is switching out the sample secret and identifier with my own).

I've used the JWT Decoder ( https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jwtdecoder ) and it looks fine.

Here's the JWT

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiIwMDQwNDkxNDU3OTM0MTYxMzI0MiIsImF1ZCI6Ikdvb2dsZSIsInR5cCI6Imdvb2dsZVwvcGF5bWVudHNcL2luYXBwXC9pdGVtXC92MSIsImV4cCI6MTM5MjkxNTg3NCwiaWF0IjoxMzkwMzIzODc0LCJyZXF1ZXN0Ijp7Im5hbWUiOiJEYW4ncyBQaWVjZSBvZiBDYWtlIiwiZGVzY3JpcHRpb24iOiJUZXN0IFB1cmNoYXNlIDEiLCJwcmljZSI6IjEwLjUwIiwiY3VycmVuY3lDb2RlIjoiVVNEIiwic2VsbGVyRGF0YSI6InVzZXJfaWQ6MTIyNDI0NSxvZmZlcl9jb2RlOjMwOTg1NzY5ODcsYWZmaWxpYXRlOmFrc2RmYm92dTlqIn19.SHwbbWiJMnyXxui-WbaDs3Z1_7mdn5lFWCJatmug1Rg

Can anyone help out?

Thanks!
-Daniel

UPDATE: I just generated a JWT using the ruby sample code here https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial and when using my sandbox secret and ID it's fine but when I use my own secret and seller id it fails. Here's generated JWT from Ruby:

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiIwMDQwNDkxNDU3OTM0MTYxMzI0MiIsImF1ZCI6Ikdvb2dsZSIsInR5cCI6Imdvb2dsZS9wYXltZW50cy9pbmFwcC9pdGVtL3YxIiwiZXhwIjoxMzkwMzUzOTU0LCJpYXQiOjEzOTAzNTAzNTQsInJlcXVlc3QiOnsibmFtZSI6IlBpZWNlIG9mIENha2UiLCJkZXNjcmlwdGlvbiI6IlZpcnR1YWwgY2hvY29sYXRlIGNha2UgdG8gZmlsbCB5b3VyIHZpcnR1YWwgdHVtbXkiLCJwcmljZSI6IjEwLjUwIiwiY3VycmVuY3lDb2RlIjoiVVNEIiwic2VsbGVyRGF0YSI6InVzZXJfaWQ6MTIyNDI0NSxvZmZlcl9jb2RlOjMwOTg1NzY5ODcsYWZmaWxpYXRlOmFrc2RmYm92dTlqIn19.6enjLDpM-fxg69-XtcllsyVXBqRNbdhhBzXSr7jmyCM

I still get a merchant_error when I call buy() with the above jwt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you switch to your "own" (assuming you meant *production* id/secret) are you also switching your calls to [production](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#library) `buy()`

```
<script src="https://wallet.google.com/inapp/lib/buy.js"></script>
```

---

### Update:

Useful info referencing @Danprime's comment:

- Chrome Apps -> [Wallet for Digital Goods](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/google_wallet.html)

> For Apps, you must call buy() with an extra parameter called *parameters*. This parameter currently has one field, *env*, which specifies the environment in which to process a payment. You can set this field to either *prod* (production server that accepts real credit cards), or *sandbox* (test server that accepts test credit cards to simulate transactions). The default setting is sandbox.

Comment: In this case it was a packaged app so the distinction isn't so much in the javascript src but the env flag should be set to 'prod' in the parameters. 

So it should be `google.payments.inapp.buy({
    parameters: {env: 'prod'},
    jwt: jwt,
    success: logSuccess,
    failure: logFailure
  });`

Answer (score 0):

Your type is doubly escaped google/payments/inapp/item/v1 also in the jwt, the issuer looks like it starts with 00.

Are you using PHP to generate it?  There should be an option to convert the object to JSON without escaping strings.

Can you double check that it actually begins with 00?

Comment: Yes, I am using PHP to generate it. Here's my current code:
<?php
require_once 'jwt.php'; // including luciferous lib 
require_once 'config.php'; //include secrets
$payload = array(
  "iss" => $sellerIdentifier,
  "aud" => "Google",
  "typ" => "google/payments/inapp/item/v1",
  "exp" => time() + (60*60*24),
  "iat" => time(),
  "request" => array (
    "name" => "Cake",
    "description" => "Desc",
    "price" => "1.50",
    "currencyCode" => "USD",
    "sellerData" => "user_id:122,offer_code:309,affiliate:aks",
  )
);
$cakeToken = JWT::encode($payload, $sellerSecret);
echo $cakeToken;
?>

Comment: Thanks @peng-ying
Is the issuer the same as the wallet ID? If so, my wallet id begins with 00

I followed the php code and suggested library here
https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial

Comment: Can you check the update? I generated the JWT using ruby code instead of php. I suspect it has something to do with my wallet/seller id.

Comment: @Danprime Probably worth asking - when you switch to your "own" (assuming you meant _production_ id/secret) are you also switching your calls to production `buy()`? Hth...

Comment: @EdSF Thank you so much! Can you put your comment in the reply section so I can mark it as correct?